# How to Inject an Array Variable into a PowerShell Runspace via New-Variable

Tags: c#, powershell

Assume I have created and opened runspace via

```
            var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            rs.Open();
```

Let's further assume that I want to add a variable into that runspace that is typed as an array by using the New-Variable cmdlet like so:

```
            // create a pipeline to add the variable into the runspace
            var pipeline = PowerShell.Create();
            // create a command object, add commands and parameters to it...
            var cmd = new PSCommand();
            cmd.AddCommand("New-Variable");
            cmd.AddParameter("Name", "foo");
            cmd.AddParameter("Value", "@()");
            // associate the command with the pipeline and runspace, and then invoke
            pipeline.Commands = cmd;
            pipeline.Runspace = rs;
            pipeline.Invoke();
```

The code works and I get no errors, but the variable 'foo' is not created as an array type. I've tried many different variations on "@()", but none of them have panned out thus far. Ultimately, I think the question boils down to how to properly format the Value argument to New-Variable so that 'foo' will be interpreted as an empty PowerShell array type.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PSCommand.AddParameter` takes a string for the parameter name, and an **object** for the parameter value.  See the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd182483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You should put a "real" empty array, not a string representing the powershell script equivalent.

```
cmd.AddParameter("Value", new object[0]);
```

Comment: Hi latkin, thanks for your answer. I am able to now create the variable as requested, but what I was looking for was how to format text read from a file to be interpreted correctly as me requesting an array type. I'm constructing my pipelines from XML and would prefer (if it's possible) to know a-priori the text format to declare various types. If there's no other way, then I'll give your answer the credit it is due. I would have voted up your answer (as well as Keith Hill's) but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are doing it all from text, you can look at the `AddScript` methods.  For example, `var cmd = new PSCommand().AddScript("$myVar = @()");` will generate a new variable named `$myVar`.

Comment: I originally tried AddScript, but I ended up with a mixture of scripts and commands because some parameters required special formatting and others didn't. E.g., when reading a Filter parameter from text, I found I needed to surround the script block with () rather than {}: e.g. for Get-ADUser, specifying the script block as {name -like "test*"}, would not work, but specifying the script block as (name -like "test*") would work. With such weirdnesses abounding, I believe that if I can get the formatting for @() right, it will work and make my overall parser more simple.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, you can do this directly in C# like so:

```
pipeline.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set("foo", new object[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the response that saved me is:

If you are doing it all from text, you can look at the `AddScript` methods. For example, `var cmd = new PSCommand().AddScript("$myVar = @()");` will generate a new variable named `$myVar`.

Example in C# code :

```
foreach (Collaborator collab in collabs)
                {
                    counter ++;
                    arrayUsers.Append("@(\"" + collab.mail + "\", \"" + collab.url + "\")");
                    if (counter < numbercollabs)
                        arrayUsers.Append(",");
                }
                string arrayUsersPowerShell =  arrayUsers.ToString();
and then :

using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
                {
 powerShellInstance.AddScript("$d = get-date; " +
                        "$arrayUsers = @(" + arrayUsersPowerShell + "); " +
                        "$d | Out-String; $arrayUsers[0][1]");
...
Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();
...
}
```

So we can construct the array correctly